# how to normalize PWM if the value exceeds the maximum speed limit

Tags: mobile-robot, kinematics, inverse-kinematics, pwm

I have implemented inverse kinematics for nonholonomic mobile wheeled robots, and the RPM range of the motor that I used is **-50 to 50**, while for PWM is from **1300 to 1700**. But in certain cases, the RPM that generated from inverse kinematics exceeds the maximum speed. How to normalize it so the RPM or PWM does not exceed the maximum speed so the robot can run properly and reach the target?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking .... if you do not want a value to exceed a preset limit, then you simply adjust the value when it goes past the limit

Comment: Add the equations you are using for better help. In many cases you can parameterize to have a path, and a speed along the path, reducing the speed until all actuators are able to keep up. But your question is unclear.

Comment: @jsotola How to adjust it?